# Status/progress of automatic pull upload through Vimeo API

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I am developing a c# application to upload videos to Vimeo throough the Vimeo API. Everything's gone fine so far, but I cannot find a way to check the progress of video uploading to Vimeo when using automatic pull uploads. I don't want percentage values (which we can derive in regular uploads), but just a success or failure response would suffice. Is there any way I can do this through an API call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response of your inital POST request to `/me/videos` is the full clip representation. On that representation is a `status` field, that will contain one of the following values:

- uploading
- transcoding
- uploading_error
- transcoding_error
- available
- quota_exceeded

The `uri` of that representation is an API endpoint that you can store, and call again in the future to receive an updated `status`.

eg:

```
POST https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos
type=streaming&link=http://example.com/my/video/mp4

{
    "uri": "/videos/12345",
    .....truncated.....
    "status": "uploading"
}
```

[some time later]

```
GET https://api.vimeo.com/videos/12345

{
    "uri": "/videos/12345",
    .....truncated.....
    "status": "available"
}
```

Comment: thanks! you should add this to the api documentation that you can call this to check the status (for the dumber people like me).

Comment: We have new documentation coming very soon, documenting every single API response, and including this status information in the upload docs. If you want early access you can ask for it! https://vimeo.com/help/contact

Comment: Two years later: docs still not there. This may be pushing the "very soon" expression.

Comment: 3 years later an the https://developer.vimeo.com/api/guides/start has tons of API docs and even a way to try out every endpoint. You can run it as your user or in the scope of your app.